# How to create range table based on table values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table

TableA

```
ID  Value
1       125  
2   400  
3   99  
4   130  
5   300  
6   350  
7   399  
..  
..
```

I want below table as a Output where range off set (100) is pre defined. Range value 100= TableA values between 0-100, 200 means 101-200

ResultTable

```
Range   Count  
100 1  
200 2  
300 1  
400 3  
..    
..
```

What is the best way to do it any idea suggestions.

Comment: Your second table has a count of 1 for 300, but TableA has 300 and 350.  Shouldn't the count be 2?  Or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

Comment: 300  means values between 201 to 300 so it would only include 300, 350 will come in range 301 to 400.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on RDMS you are using, the syntax will be a bit different (example is for Oracle), but general idea is

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT CAST(value/100 as INT)*100 as range, count(*) as cnt
GROUP BY CAST(value/100 as INT)*100
FROM old_table;
```

Comment: a1ex07 was a minute faster. Here is SQL server version of it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cfbd/11

Comment: In both solutions if there is not any value present for any range, then there wont be any entry for that range but I want 0 instead.

Comment: Then you need to create a new (temporary) table or inline view that has all the ranges you are interested in...